# is there a way to not remove the focus from a button inside v-for?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have three buttons like a choice in a page, and when user selects one of them, the background color is changed by :focus on css and when user clicks on submit button which runs a function and does not make the page reloading but the focus is removed from chosen button and background color changes back, how I can keep button focused despite clicking on submit button?

```
<button class="btn btn-lg text-white mark-answers" 
 v-for="(item, index) in markAnswers" :key="index" v-on:click="answerMarked">
   <span style="color: #000;">   {{ item.answer }}       </span>
```

---

```
.mark-answers  {

font-size: 23px !important;
font-weight: bold;
display:list-item !important;
background-color: #fb3;
width: 500px;

}

.mark-answers:hover {

background-color: #ffd98a;
} 

.mark-answers:focus {

background-color:#f7f2ff;
}
```

Comment: Show us some code, please. But in general, for a stateful element, you could use a checkbox or a radio button.

Comment: I've edited my post and added the code

Comment: Does the form submit?

Comment: actually it does not submit, a function runs and check the asnwer

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to style the `:focus` state if you need the `button` to retain this style when it's no longer focused. You can however add a `selected` class to the button based on your current state in Vue and style this instead. You can use conditional class names (`item.marked` is the selected value in state, not sure what you use at the moment):

```
<button 
  :class="{
    'btn': true,
    'btn-lg': true,
    'marked': item.marked,
  }"
  v-for="(item, index) in markAnswers" 
  :key="index" 
  v-on:click="answerMarked"
>
  <span style="color: #000;">{{ item.answer }}</span> 
</button>
```

If it's some kind of quiz form where you can only mark one answer, it's probably better to use radio buttons (`<input type="radio" />`). You can also style them (or more like their `label`) any way you want.

Comment: how can I implement it on vue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this and now when I select each of the buttons it will gets my desire background color for selected button and not lose it even if the submit button of the page is clicked.

```
 <button class="btn btn-lg text-white align-self-center mark-answers" 
 v-for="(item, index) in markAnswers" :key="index" v-on:click="answerMarked(index)" 
 v-bind:style="[(quiz.markedIndex == (index)) ? {backgroundColor: '#f7f2ff'} : {backgroundColor: ''}]">
```

---

```
 methods: {
 answerMarked: function(index) {

 this.quiz.markedIndex = index;

    },
 },
```